# Twitter OAuth throws 'Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value oob' on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

So I'm currently trying to get authorization for twitter working by making use of the [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) plugin I've tried to get it working with both OAuth1 and OAuth2 both unsuccessfully and with different errors/problems.

So for OAuth2 I get this response

> Whoa there!
>   There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

I'm using the following piece of code for this

```
let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
            consumerKey: Twitter.consumerKey,
            consumerSecret: Twitter.consumerSecret,
            authorizeUrl: Twitter.authorizeURL,
            accessTokenUrl: Twitter.accessTokenURL,
            responseType: Twitter.responseType!)

let state = generateState(withLength: 20)

        oauthswift.authorize(
            withCallbackURL: "https://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/twitter",
            scope: "",
            state: state,
            success: { credential, response, parameters in
                print("logged in with \(credential), with response \(response) and parameters \(parameters)")
            },
            failure: { error in
                print("error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        )
```

Then I moved on to using OAuth1 which gives me the error
`Desktop applications only support the auth_callback value 'oob'` while I'm obviously trying to do this from an iOS application.

the code I used here is as follows

```
let oauthTwitter = OAuth1Swift(
            consumerKey: "myKey",
            consumerSecret: "mySecret",
            requestTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
            authorizeUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
            accessTokenUrl: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token")

oauthswift.authorize(
            withCallbackURL: "https://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/twitter",
            scope: "",
            state: state,
            success: { credential, response, parameters in
                print("logged in with \(credential), with response \(response) and parameters \(parameters)")
            },
            failure: { error in
                print("error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        )
```

I'm hoping someone is able to tell me what I'm doing wrong here because I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: For the OAuth1 error? did you properly set the callback url in the Twitter console?

Comment: Yes the problem ended up my url scheme being in the wrong format it had a `_` in it which isn't allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up to be that I had setup the wrong url scheme. It contained a `_` which isn't allowed.

Comment: Hey NoSixties. I've got the same problem. My schemes do not have underscores. Did you get it working for OAuth1 or 2? Any chance of you posting working code? Your OAuth2 code references a "Twitter" type to obtain the strings. I'm trying to use OAuth2.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't set a callback URL for the app on Twitter Dev site - https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps